# How to display some of the posts in specific places on page?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I want to display a specific post in the middle of the page among other regular posts(check screenshot)

I know I could use front matter with something like `featured: true` but is there any other way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple. Just do this:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% if forloop.index == 1 or forloop.index == 4 %}
    output wide post
  {% else %}
    output normal post
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better answer: create similar divs around each post, and target them with CSS like this:

```
div {width: 50℅;}
div:nth-child(1), div:nth-child(4) {width: 100%;}
```

Layout should be in CSS, if possible.